# How to configure sonata_intl timezone?

Tags: datetime, symfony, timezone, sonata-admin, symfony-sonata

I've installed SonataIntlBundle for Symfony 2.0 (I can't use > 2.0 version for a constraint of my server). In my config.yml:

```
sonata_intl:
    timezone:
        default: Europe/Madrid
```

but I get this Exception:

> InvalidTypeException: Invalid type for path "sonata_intl.timezone". Expected scalar, but got array.

When a change the configuration in `config.yml` with this:

```
sonata_intl:
    timezone: Europe/Madrid
```

it works but nothing happens and dates still are shown in English not in Spanish as I want.

Someone knows how can I configured this bundle for Symfony 2.0 and it finally works or some way to get dates in list in sonataadminbundle in Spanish?

Answer (score 1):

The 2.0 branch is not supported by Sensio and Sonata Project ...

I don't get why you cannot install symfony2.3 on your server ?

Comment: Yes, there is version for symfony 2.0 [link] https://github.com/sonata-project/SonataIntlBundle/tree/symfony2.0. I can't install symfony 2.1+ because my hosting have still installed php 5.3.2.